# Add a transparent overlay to all LI not in focus

Tags: jquery, overlay

I have list of products within an LI what I need to do is when I hover over a product I need all other LI (Products) to get a slight overlay to them, so the product that is hovered over is more prominant.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just adjust the opacity on the non-hovered `li`s and set the opacity to `1` for the hovered `li`?

```
ul:hover li {
  opacity: .8;
}
ul:hover li:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**See it on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TXfKG/**

**UPDATE:** Like @amustill mentioned, if you care about IE6, you can add support for it with another property: `filter: alpha(opacity=50);`

Comment: I like that better than the jsFiddle I posted.  Much easier. +1

Comment: Thats great thanks... for some reason I was expecting it to involve JS :) many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this ***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ke27y/)***:

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
    <li>list item 3</li>
    <li>list item 4</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
li { padding: 10px; background: #ccc; border: solid 1px black; cursor: pointer; }
```

**jQuery:**

```
var $listItems = $("ul li");

$listItems.hover(function() {

    $listItems.not(this).css("opacity", "0.5");

}, function() {

    $listItems.not(this).css("opacity", "1.0");    

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CSS-only solution, with a JS fix for IE6.

http://jsbin.com/asico4/3

Edit: Updated link, left in a typo.